# Collection To Array Then To Range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, collections

I have 2d matrix in Excel filled with numbers and zeros. I needed numbers from each row of matrix to be listed without blanks (here without zeros) that's why I added them to collection. Than I used function I found at Stackoverlow  for converting collection to array which I needed to write the rows back to Excel. The solution works almost fine except I get full row filled with numbers of the same value in case when there is only 1 number in the matrix. The problem seems to occur during writing back values to cells. Secondly how can I get rid of these #N/D in my results? Screen and code attached, thank you.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/76jRt.jpg

```
Option Explicit
Public Function CollectionToArray(myCol As Collection) As Variant

Dim result  As Variant
Dim cnt     As Long

ReDim result(myCol.Count - 1)

For cnt = 0 To myCol.Count - 1
result(cnt) = myCol(cnt + 1)
Next cnt

CollectionToArray = result

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

Dim cell, k As Variant
Dim i  As Integer
Dim myCol As New Collection
Dim grKol, Destination As Range

Set grKol = Range("D4:BA4")
Set Destination = Range("D20:R20")


For i = 1 To 50
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(grKol.Offset(i - 1, 0)) = 0 Then 
Exit For
For Each cell In grKol.Offset(i - 1, 0)
    If cell > 0 Then
    myCol.Add cell
    End If
Next cell
k = CollectionToArray(myCol)
Destination.Offset(i, 0) = k
Set myCol = Nothing
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you're doing this in the most efficient manner. Looping through a collection is much faster with a `For Each` loop rather than by index, and you'd probably be better off writing the entire output all in one hit.

Skeleton code to achieve the above would look something like this:

```
Dim data As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, maxDim As Long
Dim rowItems As Collection, colItems As Collection
Dim output() As Variant

'Read data into an array.
data = Sheet1.Range("D4:R18").Value

'Loop through each item to populate the collections.
Set rowItems = New Collection
For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
    Set colItems = New Collection
    For j = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
        'Add item if it isn't a 0.
        If data(i, j) <> 0 Then colItems.Add data(i, j)
    Next
    'Add the items to the row collection if
    'it contains 1 or more items.
    If colItems.Count > 0 Then
        rowItems.Add colItems
        'Keep a note of the max number of items
        'to resize the output array.
        If colItems.Count > maxDim Then maxDim = colItems.Count
    End If
Next

'Set the output array size.
ReDim output(1 To rowItems.Count, 1 To maxDim)

'Populate the array.
i = 1
For Each colItems In rowItems
    j = 1
    For Each data In colItems
        output(i, j) = data
        j = j + 1
    Next
    i = i + 1
Next

'Write the output array to sheet.
Sheet1.Range("D21").Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
```

Comment: I certainly wasn't doing it in most efficient manner (I am two weeks into VBA). Your solution works perfectly and I have to take time to mull it over. Thank you very much Ambie

Answer (score 1):

Few suggested changes:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim cell, k As Variant
    Dim i  As Integer
    Dim myCol As New Collection
    Dim grKol, Destination As Range

    Set grKol = Range("D4:BA4")
    Set Destination = Range("D20") '<<### doesn't this get overwritten in your loop?

    For i = 1 To 50

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(grKol) > 0 Then
            For Each cell In grKol.Cells
                If cell.Value > 0 Then myCol.Add cell.Value '<< needs Value here
            Next cell

            k = CollectionToArray(myCol)
            Destination.Resize(1, UBound(k) + 1).Value = k '<< fill only needed cells
            Set myCol = New Collection
        End If

        Set grKol = grKol.Offset(1, 0)
        Set Destination = Destination.Offset(1, 0)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim this also works nice, the only issue I have is that output data is repeated another 2 times and I can't find why.

Comment: Well your posted code has `For i=1 to 50` which on review doesn't match your screenshot, so you may need to make some adjustments...